# Django and NoSQL, any ready-to-use library?

Tags: django, nosql, django-database, schemaless

So far Django has good integration with several RDBMS. NoSQL, schema-less and document-oriented DBMS are picking up. What's the status of integration those on-trend and fashionable DBMSes with Django? Are there any production-ready or at least ready-to-use libraries for Django?

So far I have these at hand:

- http://github.com/lethain/comfy-django-example
- http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/276069660/nosql-libraries#mongodb-python

Comment: @philipxy: Feel free to move it to another stack exchange site. No point removing points from an old question which served its purpose

Comment: @Eyeslandic: Feel free to move it to another stack exchange site. No point removing points from an old question which served its purpose

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pre 1.0, django ORM underwent a major queryset re-factor. One of the reasons for this was "This re-factor enables us to support non relational backends".

The official support I think is definitely on the cards; but I think there were more pressing matters for 1.1 and 1.2(now in beta).

However, there are of course several independent efforts to use non relational databases with django, including, but not limited to the following:

- [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) by Waldemar, who made django work on the appengine using the appengine patch.
- Using django with mongo db, by Kevin Fricovsky: http://bitbucket.org/gumptioncom/django-non-relational/
- Using django with couch db, an old post, by Eric: http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/using-couchdb-django/

Answer (score 2):

[Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/)- the Java graph database (on the other end of the NoSQL spectrum)- also has [initial support](http://journal.thobe.org/2009/12/seamless-neo4j-integration-in-django.html).

EDIT:

I've spent quite a while fleshing this support out and moving to a remote protocol. You can see the results on [GitHub](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django).

Comment: thanks Matt! I'm excited to know this.

Answer (score 0):

Until there is official Django support of a MongoDB back-end, for auto-admin, etc. (wouldn't that be so great). I would take a look at [mongokit](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit), which is a thin wrapper over pymongo. There's a few alternatives, but mongokit has comprehensive documentation and is under active development.